# React Js - unit testing - sanitizeEmail

Tags: jestjs, enzyme

Running a unit test using ReactJS jest and enzyme.I am not really sure how to test the following  correctly:

```js
sanitizeEmail = email => {
  let result = email;
  if (result.indexOf('@') !== -1 && result.substring(0, result.indexOf('@')).length > 3) {
    const end = result.indexOf('@');
    let temp = '';
    for (const i in result.substring(4, end)) {
      temp = temp + '*';
    }
    result = result.substring(0, 3) + temp + result.substring(end, result.length);
  }
  return result;
};
```

I want to make sure this function gets called, the test is passing at the moment but it's not affecting its coverage
Here is my test at the moment

```js
it('Test sanitizeEmail function', () => {
  wrapper.setProps({});
  wrapper.find('CLASSNAME').setState({
    permissionsLoaded: true,
    localPermissions: { [globals.UI_NOTIFICATION]: true }
  });
  wrapper.update();
  expect(
    wrapper
      .find('CLASSNAME')
      .instance()
      .sanitizeEmail('test')
  ).toEqual('test');
  expect(wrapper.find('CLASSNAME').state('permissionsLoaded')).toBeTruthy();
});
```